# OCaml Abstract typed functions

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, gadt

I want to accomplish something like this, but I can't quite get the syntax down.

```
type _ s = Var : 'a -> 'a s
type _ t = 
| AA :('a -> 'a s) -> 'c t
| AB : ('a -> 'b s) -> 'c t
let apply_to x = function
| AA g -> g x
| AB g -> g x
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, a type like `'a -> 'a s` makes sense. You can see how the parameter is going to work. A type like `('a -> 'a s) -> 'c t` doesn't make sense (to me). I don't see where the `'c` type is supposed to come from. The same goes for `'a -> 'b s`. I don't see where the `'b` is supposed to come from. Types like this are usually associated with code that doesn't actually return at all (undefined code, code that raises an exception, etc.).

It's (very) possible there's a subtlety of GADTs that I don't understand, but maybe this will help at least a little.

Comment: So I guess what I'm trying to accomplish is having a function type in a gadt,  which can be applied.